# Coding streets in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, streets

Can you provide me a little know-how of how you could code your streets as shown in the figure.[image]
Initial class is assigned as A,B,C... and when certain street(say A) branches, it is coded , as A1, A2 with even and odd numbers corresponding to side the branching occurs. Similarly the number is added -either 1 or 2 as branching occurs. I believe network analysis with hierarcy is a good starting point.

I am okay with doing some Python and ArcPy.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I cannot see classes A, B or C on your picture, and I think that needs to be the starting point to try and understand your proposed naming algorithm.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.